# Exercise of Summation

Tags: calculus

How do I find an explicit formula for the next sum?

$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left ( e^{\frac{2}{n}} \right )^{i}$

Thanks for the help

Comment: This is the sum of a geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

Take note, that for ${\displaystyle r\neq 1}$, the sum of the first n terms of a geometric series is :

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k = a\bigg(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\bigg)$$

Thus, fitting the known formula above for your specific example with $a=1$, it is :

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \big(e^{2/n})^i= \frac{e^{2/n + 2} -1}{e^{2/n}-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left ( e^{\frac{2}{n}} \right )^{i}=\dfrac{1-e^\frac{2n+2}{n}}{1-e^\frac{2}{n}}$$by using the formula of sum of geometric series